# I want to send the particular one role name from drop down to controller on submit button action

Tags: html, spring

here is the html.

```
<form action="/submitrolename" method="post" model="command">
<td>                    
    <label for="radio2"><input type="radio" name="test1" value="radio2"  />Role </label><br>
            Select Role : <select  name="for_radio2[]" class="radio2" disabled="true">
                                    <c:forEach items="${listRole}" var="role">
                                                <option value="${role.roleName}">
                                                    <c:out value="${role.roleName}" />
                                                </option>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                    </select>
                <input type="submit" value = "Check"  style="height:25px;width:50px">
</td>
```

Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitrole", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String addruleSerch(@ModelAttribute ("SpringWeb") Role command,  ModelMap model) {
  model.addAttribute("roleName", command.getRoleName());
  command.getRoleName(); 
  System.out.println("********" +command.getRoleName());
  }
```

I am trying to pass the select rolename from drop down to controller on button action, but i ubnable to do it, while i passing its  shows null value, how do i fix this problem, please help me,

Thank You for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring uses request parameter names to bind values to bean properties. The parameter name must match the bean property name. In your case you need to rename your select element from for_radio2[] to roleName to match the roleName property in the Role class.

Comment: if rename the select name in that case the radio button is not working please could you hlep me to do this

Comment: why do you need the radio button for ?

Comment: there have two field one is for Rule & Another is for Role

Comment: Match the names as well for the radio. What field is it supposed to be bound to in Role class

Comment: @ ekem chitsiga while i am rename  the dropdown with ruleNmae the value is passing but the radio button action is not work, its bound with ruleName